# How can I serve web pages on a single domain from 2 servers on 2 ip addresses

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, dns, ip-address

I have an old website `www.myoldsite.com`. It's part html files and part wordpress blog (served at `www.myoldsite.com/blog`). It's served from a shared hosting package at 1&1

I also have an ecommerce store at `www.mystore.com` served from a dedicated server that I manage (and share with other django based sites).

I want to point `www.myoldsite.com` to my dedicated server and serve it up from there. The new site will sell products from the ecommerce store (hence the reason for moving it over) However I don't want to loose the seo juice from the blog.

Also I don't want install php or mysql on my dedicated machine, or adjust apache at all.

Is it possible to leave the old blog where it is and adjust dns / apache settings in order to continue serving pages from `www.myoldsite.com/blog` once I've change the A record to point to my dedicated server's ip address.

I'm planning to scrape the database from the blog and then build it into my django site but I suspect it'll take me a few days to move it all over. I don't want to spend a load of time doing this, only to find that I've missed something and could have achieved the same thing in half an hour.

I guess I just want to confirm that I can't serve web pages on a single domain from 2 servers on 2 ip addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to configure Apache as a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to point to your old machine. It will transparently pass requests under the "blog/" path to the blog site.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.